# How to scrape Instagram using Python using Selenium after Instagram changed their API process? I'm unable to find all the entries, can only find 12

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to scrape Instagram using Python and Selenium. Goal is to get the url of all the posts, number of comments, number of likes, etc.

I was able to scrape some data but for some reason the page doesn't show more than 12 latest entries. I'm unable to figure out a way to show all the other entries. I've even tried scrolling down and then reading the page but it's only giving 12. I checked the source and am unable to find how to get the rest of the entries. It looks like the 12 entries are embedded into the script tag and I don't see it anywhere else.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/fazeapparel/?hl=en')
source = driver.page_source
data=bs(source, 'html.parser')
body = data.find('body')
script = body.find('script', text=lambda t: t.startswith('window._sharedData'))
page_json = script.text.split(' = ', 1)[1].rstrip(';')
data = json.loads(page_json)
```

Using the data retrieved, I was able to find the information and collect them.

```
for each in data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']:
    link = 'https://www.instagram.com'+'/p/'+each['node']['shortcode']+'/'
    posttext = each['node']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text'].replace('\n','')
    comments = each['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count']
    likes = each['node']['edge_liked_by']['count']
    postimage = each['node']['thumbnail_src']
    isvideo = each['node']['is_video']
    postdate = time.strftime('%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(each['node']['taken_at_timestamp']))
    links.append([link, posttext, comments, likes, postimage, isvideo, postdate])
```

I've even created a scroll function to scroll the window and then scraping the data but it's only returning 12.

Is there any way I can get more than 12 entries? This account has 46 entries and I'm unable to find it anywhere in the code. Please Help!

Edit: I think the data is embedded within React so it's not showing all the posts

Answer (score 0):

Have you added using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI ? It has a WebDriverWait and you can wait for the element to be visible. Sorry for doing this in C#. 
Boxes should returns all the posts.

Again, I know it isn't in Python, but I hope it helps.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\admin\\downloads", options);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, time);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.instagram.com\cnn");

 IWebElement mainDocument = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.TagName("body")));

IWebElement element  = mainDocument.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#react-root > section > main > div > div._2z6nI > article > div > div");

IList <IWebElement> boxes =  element.FindElements(By.TagName("div"));

foreach (var posts in boxes)
{
 //do stuff here

}
```

EDIT:

It is making a ajax call on the back end to load the next posts when you scroll. One way might be to run a script that scrolls down. You would want to call this script in selenium. I would add logic to with a timer to wait while the script runs and check if it returns "STOP". Any type of thread sleeps blocks the thread. I would use some start of timer to call the method that runs my script.

```
function scrollDown() {
 //once this bottom element disappears we found all the posts
var bottom = document.querySelector('._4emnV')

if (bottom != null) {
    window.scroll(0,999999)
 }
 else
 {
    return "STOP"
 }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to put some try and catch to handle any exceptions. I just threw that together really quick.

Comment: You're saying you were able to get all now 48 posts? For me I used scroller to bring the elements into view but still only able to get 12 last posts. I think the issue is with the items being inside a React div

Comment: Adding this to my original post.